# Covariance of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

$U(t)=e^{-\mu t}W(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}}{2\mu})$.
The problem is to find $Cov[U(t),U(t+s)]$.

I used the identity, 
$W(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}}{2\mu})=W(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}e^{2\mu s}}{2\mu })e^{-\mu s}$, which resulted in the wrong answer of $\frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu}$. I should be getting $\frac{\sigma^2 e^{-\mu s}}{2\mu}$.

Why is this identity wrong? It seems like it is only a scale transformation, with $\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}}{2\mu}$ the variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $U(t)=e^{-\mu t}W(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}}{2\mu})$, then 
\begin{eqnarray*}\mbox{Cov}[U(t),U(t+s)]&=&\mbox{Cov}\left[e^{-\mu t}W\left(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}}{2\mu}\right),e^{-\mu (t+s)}W\left(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu (t+s)}}{2\mu}\right)\right]\\[10pt]
&=& e^{-\mu t} e^{-\mu (t+s)} \mbox{Cov}\left[W\left(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}}{2\mu}\right),W\left(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu (t+s)}}{2\mu}\right)\right]\\[10pt]
&=& e^{-\mu t} e^{-\mu (t+s)}\,\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}}{2\mu}\\[10pt]
&=&  e^{-\mu s}\,\frac{\sigma^2 }{2\mu}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks, but I just don't see why the identity gives the wrong answer...

Comment: The identity $W(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}}{2\mu})=W(\frac{\sigma^2e^{2\mu t}e^{2\mu s}}{2\mu })e^{-\mu s}$ is not correct. These two random variables have the same mean and variance, but are **not** the same random variable. In particular, their covariance with another random variable is not usually going to be the same.

Comment: I wondered as well that may be. Thank you.