# How to identify an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process? Aquestion concerning the notes on SPDE's from Walsh.

Tags: stochastic-calculus

In page 7  from the notes ["An introduction to SPDE's"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0074917) from Walsh, one reads:

[image]

If we compute the covariance of $V_s$ we obtain (for $s\leq t$)

$$ Cov (V_s, V_t) = Cov(U_{s,a +bs}, U_{t,a +bt}) = e^{-|s - t|} e^{-|b||s-t|}  = e^{-(1+|b|)|s-t|} \tag{*}$$

Compare with wikipedia's value for the covariance of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes [covariance function for Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30791/covariance-function-for-brownian-motion?noredirect=1&lq=1#30793)

Also checking [Covariance of Ornstein - Uhlenbeck Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913862/covariance-of-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process) and [Covariance of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408394/covariance-of-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process), the values expressed there do not seem to match my calculations.

Are the computation in $(*)$ correct? This characterizes the process as an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process? Why do we see these different expressions for the 
covariances?